# Projection not working as expected in mongodb npm version 3.1.8

Tags: mongodb

```
 const data = await req.db.collection('Collection').find({},{'key1':1,'key2':1,'key3':1}).toArray();
```

Isn't the above query supposed to give the documents with key1,key2 and key3?? Instead it showing me the complete information from the documents?

Comment: You should be using [`.project()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) instead of a second argument to `find()`. The separate chained method has been standard in the API for some time now.

Comment: .project() works on the application but its not working on the mongo shell.
db.getCollection(...).find(...).project is not a function :

Comment: Becuase it's not for the "mongo shell". The shell works differently to the NodeJS API. Most language drivers use a similar thing, and the "shell" actually has not had "significant" updates for a couple of years now.

Comment: I try to use .project() on  findOne but its not working. Does it have other way of defining projection?